# How to Plot a function of two variables in Julia with pyplot

Tags: matplotlib, plot, julia

I'm trying to plot a function of two variables with pyplot in Julia. The working starting-point is the following (found here at StackOverflow):

```
function f(z,t)
    return z*t
end

z = linspace(0,5,11)
t = linspace(0,40,4)

for tval in t
   plot(z, f(z, tval))
end
show()
```

This works right for me and is giving me exactly what I wanted:
[a field of lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsAgi.png).

My own functions are as follows:

```
## needed functions ##

const gamma_0 = 6
const Ksch = 1.2
const Kver = 1.5

function Kvc(vc)
    if vc <= 0 
        return 0
    elseif vc < 20 
        return (100/vc)^0.1
    elseif vc < 100
        return 2.023/(vc^0.153)
    elseif vc == 100
        return 1
    elseif vc > 100
        return 1.380/(vc^0.07)
    else 
        return 0
    end
end 

function Kgamma(gamma_t)
    return 1-((gamma_t-gamma_0)/100)
end

function K(gamma_t, vc)
    return Kvc(vc)*Kgamma(gamma_t)*Ksch*Kver
end
```

I've tried to plot them as follows:

```
i = linspace(0,45,10)
j = linspace(0,200,10)
for i_val in i
    plot(i,K(i,j))
end
```

This gives me the following Error:

> `isless` has no method matching isless(::Int64, ::Array{Float64,1})
>   while loading In[51], in expression starting on line 3
>
> in Kvc at In[17]:2  in anonymous at no file:4

Obviously, my function cant deal with an array.

Next try:

```
i = linspace(0,200,11)
j = linspace(0,45,11)
for i_val in i
    plot(i_val,map(K,i_val,j))
end
```

gives me a empty plot only with axes

Can anybody please give me a hint...

### EDIT

A simpler example:

```
using PyPlot
function P(n,M)
    return (M*n^3)/9550
end
M = linspace(1,5,5)
n = linspace(0,3000,3001)

for M_val in M
    plot(n,P(n,M_val))
end
show()
```

### Solution

OK, with your help I found this solution for the shortened example which works for me as intended:

```
function P(n,M)
    result = Array(Float64, length(n))
    for (idx, val) in enumerate(n)
        result[idx] = (M*val^3)/9550
    end
    return result
end
n = linspace(0,3000,3001)

for M_val = 1:5
    plot(n,P(n,M_val))
end
show()
```

This gives me [what I wanted for this shortened example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQvgE.png). The remainig question is: could it be done in a simpler more elegant way?

I'll try to apply it to the original example and post it when I'll succed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't completely follow all the details of what you're trying to accomplish, but here are examples on how you can modify a couple of your functions so that they accept and return arrays:

```
function Kvc(vc)
    result = Array(Float64, length(vc))
    for (idx, val) in enumerate(vc)
        if val <= 0
            result[idx] = 0
        elseif val < 20
            result[idx] = (100/val)^0.1
        elseif val < 100
            result[idx] = 2.023/(val^0.153)
        elseif val == 100
            result[idx] = 1
        elseif val > 100
            result[idx] = 1.380/(val^0.07)
        else
            result[idx] = 0
        end
    end
    return result
end 

function Kgamma(gamma_t)
    return ones(length(gamma_t))-((gamma_t - gamma_0)/100)
end
```

Also, for your loop, I think you probably want something like:

```
for i_val in i
    plot(i_val,K(i_val,j))
end
```

rather than `plot(i, K(i,j)`, as that would just print the same thing over and over.

Comment: Thank's for your quick answer.
What I'm trying to achieve is a plot like [this] (http://www.energie.ch/assets/images/article/Bilder/Diagramme/asynchronmaschine_kennlinie_verschiedene_frequenzen.gif). Taken from [here] (http://www.energie.ch/asynchronmaschine).

I'll shorten and simplify my original question to make my intention clearer.

Comment: @MarcelRüdiger You asked for a hint and so that's what I gave : )  It looks to me like your updated implementation is good.  I don't think there is anything obvious to be done to improve upon what you've done.

Answer (score 1):

`<` is defined for scalars. I think you need to broadcast it for arrays, i.e. use `.<`. Example:

```
julia> x = 2
2

julia> x < 3
true

julia> x < [3 4]
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching isless(::Int64, ::Array{Int64,2})
Closest candidates are:
  isless(::Real, ::AbstractFloat)
  isless(::Real, ::Real)
  isless(::Integer, ::Char)
 in <(::Int64, ::Array{Int64,2}) at .\operators.jl:54
 in eval(::Module, ::Any) at .\boot.jl:234
 in macro expansion at .\REPL.jl:92 [inlined]
 in (::Base.REPL.##1#2{Base.REPL.REPLBackend})() at .\event.jl:46

julia> x .< [3 4]
1x2 BitArray{2}:
 true  true
```